# Third moment of probability

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X_i$ be a random sample drawing from a normal distribution of $\mu,\sigma^2$.

Calculate $E[(X_i-\mu)^3)$.

**Solution:**

$E[(X_i-\mu)^3] = E[(X_i-\mu)^2 (X_i-\mu)] = E[(X_i-\mu)](X_i-\mu)$.

I am wondering how come the second term above is equal to the third term?

---

**Update:**

$\theta_1 = E[X_i]$, 
$\theta_i = E(X_i - \theta_1)^j, j = 2,3,4$

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution is completely wrong, on so many levels.

Comment: please see my update, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$What is written in that book means that $\E((X_i-\mu)^3) = \E\big( (X_i-\mu)^2(X_i-\mu)\big).$

Stein's lemma then says
$$
\E((X_i-\mu)^2(X_i-\mu)) = \E(g(X_i)(X_i-\mu)) = \sigma^2 \E(g'(X_i)) = \sigma^2\E(2(X_i-\mu)).
$$

Comment: omg....... this is so bad. Ye, I think your interpretation makes sense.

Comment: The book notation is a bit sloppy.